# estoy tratando de hacer una función con javascript pero el resultado sale undefined

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de hacer la tabla de multiplicar de un numero dado con una funcion en javascripit

```js
 var n = 2 ;
 for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
 console.log(i,"*",n,"*",i*n);

function tablamultiplicar (n) {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
  console.log(i,"*",n,"*",i*n);
  return n;
}
```

Comment: Donde te da undefined? Puedes explicar que es lo que quieres hacer?

Comment: La funcion da undefined, es decir, quiero que me haga la tabla de multiplicar pero con la función omitan la segunda y la tercera linea de codigo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que no estas llamando a la función en ningún momento.

Y creo que tienes el concepto de las variables un poco confuso.

1. Al declarar var n =2, es una variable local que no la puedes usar en las otras funciones (como norma general).
2. La variable n dentro de tablamultiplicar(n) es otra variable totalmente diferente a la anterior. No tiene nada que ver una con la otra. Es como declarar una "var n" dentro de la función.
3. ¿Para que quieres usar un return en la función? Ya estas imprimiendo por pantalla.

Por lo tanto debes llamar a la función y te funcionará sin problema.

```js
 var n = 2 ;
    
    tablamultiplicar(n);
    
    function tablamultiplicar (variable) { //variable coge el valor de n
      for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
      console.log(i,"*",variable,"=",i*variable);
    }
```

Comment: muchas gracias eso era el error

Comment: @FelipeVarelaGraciano la respuesta que te haya servido, debes marcarla con el "Tick verde" de tu izquierda, para que si en un futuro a alguien llega a esta pregunta, encuentre la respuesta que a ti te ayudó rápidamente.

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que quieres es multiplicar un numero con una función, pasando este como parámetro, puedes hacerlo así:

```
 var n = 2 ; // declaras la variable n con valor 2.

/*llamas a la función tablamultiplicar pasando el 
numero anterior como parámetro*/
 tablamultiplicar(n); 

function tablamultiplicar (n) { 
  for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) 
      console.log(i,"*",n,"=",i*n);
}
```

Aquí con el bucle, multiplicas el numero 2 en este caso, desde el 1 hasta el 10.

Resultado:

```
1 * 2 = 2
2 * 2 = 4
3 * 2 = 6
4 * 2 = 8
5 * 2 = 10
6 * 2 = 12
7 * 2 = 14
8 * 2 = 16
9 * 2 = 18
10 * 2 = 20
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por todo, eso era el error